# Error when running gibbs.msbvar() in R package MSBVAR

Tags: r

I am trying to run a Markov-Switching model in R using the MSBVAR package. I can run the `MSBVAR()` function, but when I try to simulate a posterior distribution using the function `gibbs.msbvar`, I get an error,  `could not find function "as.bit.integer"`. I little Googling suggests that `as.bit.integer` is a function int he package `bit`, and I do have that installed.

To give a bit more detail, I have compiled the package myself, and this seemed to have worked fine. Working through the example in the manual, the following code runs fine:

```
library(MSBVAR) 
data(IsraelPalestineConflict)
# Find the mode of an msbvar model
# Initial guess is based on random draw, so set seed.
set.seed(123)
 
xm <- msbvar(IsraelPalestineConflict, p=3, h=2,
           lambda0=0.8, lambda1=0.15,
           lambda3=1, lambda4=1, lambda5=0, mu5=0,
           mu6=0, qm=12,
           alpha.prior=matrix(c(10,5,5,9), 2, 2))
```

But then I try to run `gibbs.msbvar` as per the manual example:

```
  # Now sample the posterior
N1 <- 1000
N2 <- 2000
# First, so this with random permutation sampling
x1 <- gibbs.msbvar(xm, N1=N1, N2=N2, permute=TRUE)
```

That returns the following error:

```
Burn-in iteration :  1000 
Error in as.bit.integer(as.integer(ss$SS[, 1:(h - 1)])) : 
could not find function "as.bit.integer"
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, with a bit of help from a friend (Thanks Arvind!), I have solved my own problem. Posting here, in case anyone has the same issue.

The problem seems to be that `MSBVAR` requires the package `bit` for the function `as.bit.integer()`. But `as.bit.integer()` is now integrated within `as.bit()` in the `bit` package. This introduces a bug into `MSBVAR`.

This bug seems to have been fixed by Yawei Zhao. See

https://github.com/YaweiZhao/MSBVAR

He says:

> 2020-11-23 The package have not update many years.For example the 'bit' package update so that the 'MSBVAR' package`s SS.R file some function can not run by a right way.now,Daniel try to do something in order to let the package running. Patrick T. Brandt School of Economic, Political and Policy Sciences University of Texas, Dallas 800 W. Campbell Rd, Green 31 Richardson, Texas 75080 [http://www.utdallas.edu/~pbrandt](http://www.utdallas.edu/%7Epbrandt) pbrandt@utdallas.edu

Anyway, this seems to be right. I reinstalled MSBVAR from Yawei's GitHub page by running.

```
devtools::install_github("YaweiZhao/MSBVAR",dependencies = TRUE)
```

Now everything works. Thanks Yawei!